# how to import a file to my application using the context menu (right Click)

Tags: c#, shell, stream, contextmenu

i want my app to be added to the -right-click- context menu items, and i want to import files path when  i right click on a File and chose my program

i am using this code to add the app in  context menu

```
private void btnAddMenu_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    RegistryKey regmenu = null;
    RegistryKey regcmd = null;
    try
    {
        regmenu = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(MenuName);
        if(regmenu != null)
            regmenu.SetValue("",this.txtName.Text);
        regcmd = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(Command);
        if(regcmd != null)
                regcmd.SetValue("",this.txtPath.Text);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this,ex.ToString());
    }
    finally       
    {
        if(regmenu != null)
            regmenu.Close();
        if(regcmd != null)
            regcmd.Close();
    }        
}
```

so anybody knows how to import the file path into the application!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that difficult. Basically you will need to add item to the Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey registry.

You can read the parameter in the `main(string[] args)` method. It will pass it as contents of the `args` parameter. You can also get that value anywhere else in your application using the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` method.

Check out these references:

1. [Add a context menu to the Windows Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/appendmenu.aspx)
2. [Add "Open with Notepad" to the Context Menu for All Files](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/)